# NSArray of objects and Casting

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have a class `A` with a property `NSString *name`. If have an `NSArray` and add many `A` objects into this array, is casting necessary each time I retrieve an object? i.e.

```
NSString* n = (NSString*)[arr objectAtIndex:1];
```

Or is there a another way to do it kind of like in java where you have `ArrayList<A> arr`?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`NSArray` do not store information about the types of objects contained in them.  If you know for sure the types of objects in your array, you can perform a cast, either implicitly or explicitly:

```
NSString *n = [arr objectAtIndex:1];  // implicit type conversion (coercion) from id to NSString*
NSString *n = (NSString *)[arr objectAtIndex:1];  // explicit cast
```

There's no difference in runtime cost between implicit and explicit casts, it's just a matter of style.  If you get the type wrong, then what is very likely going to happen is that you'll get the dreaded `unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x12345678` exception.

If you have a heterogeneous array of different types of objects, you need to use the [`isKindOfClass:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/isKindOfClass:) method to test the class of the object:

```
id obj = [arr objectAtIndex:1];
if ([obj isKindOfClass:[NSString class] ])
{
    // It's an NSString, do something with it...
    NSString *str = obj;
    ...
}
```

Comment: It's worth noting that there is no way to distinguish between NSStrings and NSMutableStrings at runtime — they all answer YES to `isKindOfClass: [NSMutableString class]`.

Comment: @Chuck: I didn't know that. How come?

Comment: @Chuck: I noticed that NSString also returns YES to `[myNSString respondsToSelector: @"appendFormat:];`. ISTM that mutable and immutable strings are both implemented by __NSCFString and that has some internal flag telling it whether is it mutable or not. If you call `[myNSString appendFormat: @"world"];` you get an exception, but not one that indicates it does not respond to the selector. Apparently `appendFormat:` checks the immutable flag and if it is set, it raises an exception. Mutable and immutable strings are, de facto, the same class, `__NSCFString`.

Comment: @Chuck: Ok, there is also `__NSCFConstantString`, for string literals.

Comment: @Rudy: You're right. They're both implemented "on top of" CFString, whose code you [can look at](http://opensource.apple.com/source/CF/CF-550.43/CFString.c); it does indeed have a mutable flag. Some (all?) of the mutating functions call `CFAssertIsStringAndMutable()`, which, as you might guess, uses `CFAssert` to check that the string is mutable.

Comment: @John: thanks for the link. I looked at the code and this is apparently far more complicated than I expected: different types of representation, length field, length byte, etc.etc. What a mess. <g>

Answer (score 11):

`NSArray`'s `objectAtIndex:` returns a variable of type `id`. This would be roughly equivalent to returning an `Object` in Java—"we can't guarantee much about this variable's type." In Objective-C however, you can send messages to `id` variables without the compiler complaining. So, because *you* know that the array only contains `A` instances, you're good to send it the `name` message. For example, the following will compile without warning:

```
NSString *name = [[array objectAtIndex:0] name];
```

However, if you want to use dot notation (e.g. `[array objectAtIndex:0].name`), you'll need to cast the `id` to an `A *` as shown here:

```
NSString *name = ((A *)[array objectAtIndex:0]).name;
```

Comment: perfect.. just the info I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

This is the way to do it. You can actually do the above operation without casting the return since you're reading it into a NSString anyway.

Answer (score -3):

this is the way:

```
NSMutableArray  *objectsArray = [[NSMutableArray  alloc] init];

A *a= [[A alloc] init];

[objectsArray addObject:a];

[a release];
```

You don't need to worry about the proprety type

Comment: Actually no, adding to the array retains the object so after that snippet you have a retain number of +2, so you would actually need to remove the item and release it in order for it not to leak, all and all this is bad practice, I should have said this code can lead to leaks..

Comment: Daniel is right to point out that this is poor style. There is only one reference to the instance of `A`, which is through the array, but both the array and the `alloc`ing code have ownership claims on it. /cc @Chuck

Comment: Oh, terribly sorry. Long day. Ignore me.

Comment: Thx for pointing that out: But it wasn't really the point here!